# JavaScript google maps API - one one infowindow open at a time..

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

This questions relating to infowindow in the google maps API v3..

Currently I loop this function and place markers..

```
function addPostCode(zip, html) 
{
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) 
   {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: results[0].geometry.location,
         name: zip
      });
});
```

Now I would like to add an info windows with unique HTML, however I would like the following behaviour..

When an infowindow is opened by an event, any current infowindows will close leaving only the new one present..

Is this possible and how would I go about it? Finding documentation on this issue is proving difficult..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single infowindow in your initialization. In your event/listener where you want to open the infowindow, you'd set the content and open the infowindow on the marker/location on the map.

```
// Initialize infowindow
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: ''});

function add_marker(point, name, content)
{
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      dragable: false,
      clickable: true,
      name: name
   });
   marker.content = content;
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
   {
      infowindow.content = marker.content;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
   return marker;
};

function addPostCode(zip, html) 
{
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) 
   {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = add_marker(results[0].geometry.location, zip, html)
      });
});
```

This question and answer helped me out quite a bit with the single or multiple Info Window issue:

[Google Maps API v3 adding an InfoWindow to each marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158598/google-maps-api-v3-adding-an-infowindow-to-each-marker)

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentInfoWindow = ''; //Global variable

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
   {
      if(currentInfoWindow != '')
      { 
        currentInfoWindow.close();
        currentInfoWindow = '';
      }
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'COntent'});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      currentInfoWindow = infowindow;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off asking the [Google Groups for the Google Maps API v3](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/)  about this one, and any other related questions.

I haven't used API v3, but as far as I know, you can only have one info window open at a time, so this would happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this ... the first is to create a single info window and just use the [`.setOptions`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) method of the info window to update the [`content`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions).

The second way to do it is to simply set a module-level variable in your code to contain the "active" window ... and then if any infoWindow is open, call it's `.close` method before you open the new one.