# Google Maps Api adding label

Tags: google-maps, label

i'm using the the following function to create my markers from a XML file. i wish to label each market 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc where 'i' is the number. can some please please tell me how to incorporate this. thank you

```
    function createMarker(point, name, address, type, i) {
  var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  });
  return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Chart server to create dynamic icons, and set that as your marker image.

Chart server docs on using dynamic icons: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html

For example,
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|FF0000|000000 will render as [image]

and http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|FF0000|000000 will get you [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own Marker icons, and implement them onto your map, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Icons)
(It might be best to use the current Google Maps API v3 if you aren't already)

Do something like:

```
 function createMarker(point, name, address, i) {
  var image = "icon" + i + ".png";
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: name
  });
  addinfowindow(marker, html);
  return marker;
}
```

(where you have made an icon for each marker called icon1.png to icon6.png and placed in the directory)

Also for multiple info windows you may need to create a new global function addinfowindow() with a infowindow defined globally (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158598/google-maps-api-v3-adding-an-infowindow-to-each-marker/3159163#3159163)).

```
function addwindow(pmarker, phtml){


  google.maps.event.addListener(pmarker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(phtml);
    infowindow.open(map, pmarker);
  });

}
```