# Add infowindow to looped array of markers on google map using api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array that is being looped through in js to put custom markers on a google map. I need to add a hidden info window for each marker so that when it is clicked the relevant infowindow is displayed. Currently I am doing the following:

```
for(var i=0; i<google_map_item.length; i++)
    {
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(google_map_item[i].lat, google_map_item[i].lon)
        bounds.extend(latlon);
        var iconcolor = google_map_item[i].iconColor;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlon,
            icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=" + (i + 1) + "|"+iconcolor+"|000000",
            type: 'flat',
            icon_color: '#ff0000', 
            label_color: '#ffffff', 
            width: '20', 
            height: '20', 
            label_size: '11',
                            clickable: true
        });

        marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: '<b>Speed:</b> knots'
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        marker.info.open(map, marker);
                    });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

However this only creates 1 info box that displays no matter which point you click.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this blog post:

> http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/

Basically, you are overwriting each marker object with the new marker object. You need to make each marker context-specific, using `this`.

Your event listener should look like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.info.open(map, this);
});
```

You may need to make more changes to ensure you are creating new objects for each iteration. Try this and let us know!

Comment: it created a box for each one but it puts the same content in each one. The content is dynamic so will be different for each area...?

Comment: you need to make sure you are creating a new marker reference each time. Read that blog post; it discusses how to use dynamic content by storing it in the marker object.

Comment: I read that blog post when I had the problem, and the only thing that helped me was to use a callback function as described in my answer. If this works for you Matt, please let me know because it looks much simpler than the code I am using.

Answer (score 1):

From the suggestions on the right:
[Google Maps API v3 adding an InfoWindow to each marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158598/google-maps-api-v3-adding-an-infowindow-to-each-marker?rq=1)

Seems to be the answer you are looking for (using function closure).

[Working example, infowindow content from xml](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh, *this* problem....

It's a tough one if you don't know what you're looking for. I had this a few months back and it was terrifyingly hard to find the right answer, whether on StackOverflow or even in the Google Maps documentation.

I don't purport to know why this code works any more than the next man, but it worked for me, and with a little bit of tweaking on your part to fit your project, it should work for you too.

Here is the code I used. There are a few artifacts from my project in there in terms of variable names, but I've tried to strip most of it out that I could, and comment out the parts which you don't need or which you can change based on your desired behavior of the InfoWindows.

```
function initMap(){

    bldgNo =     new Object();  // YOU CAN GET
    bldgName =   new Object();  // RID OF ANY
    bldgAddr =   new Object();  // OF THESE...
    bldgGfx =    new Object();  // 
    mainMeter =  new Object();  // JUST REPLACE
    alarmCount = new Object();  // THEM WITH
    latitude =   new Object();  // WHAT YOU'LL
    longitude =  new Object();  // NEED INSTEAD.
    markersArray = [];

    google.maps.Map.prototype.clearOverlays = function() {
        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markersArray.length = 0;
        }
    }

    location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(22.413543,-137.075743);  // IN CASE YOU'LL NEED MORE
    location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(22.628202,-137.426432);  // THAN ONE LOCATION? I DID.
    myOptions = {
        zoom:15,            // BEST IS BETWEEN 12-15
        scrollwheel:false,  // EITHER TRUE OR FALSE
        center:location1,   // ONE OF THE ABOVE LAT/LNG LOCATIONS
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, or TERRAIN (all-caps)
    };
    map =       new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    icon =      new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/YOUR-IMAGE-HERE.png',new google.maps.Size(20,34),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(10,34));
    shadow =    new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/YOUR-SHADOW-IMG.png',new google.maps.Size(37,34),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(10,34));

    infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var i=1;

    $(".building").each(function(i){

        bldgNo[i] =     $(this).children(".bldg-no").html();        // YOU CAN GET
        bldgName[i] =   $(this).children(".bldg-name").html();      // RID OF ANY
        bldgAddr[i] =   $(this).children(".bldg-address").html();   // OF THESE...
        bldgGfx[i] =    $(this).children(".bldg-graphic").html();   // 
        mainMeter[i] =  $(this).children(".main-meter").html(); // JUST REPLACE
        alarmCount[i] = $(this).children(".alarm-count").html();    // THEM WITH
        latitude[i] =   $(this).children(".latitude").html();       // WHAT YOU'LL 
        longitude[i] =  $(this).children(".longitude").html();      // NEED INSTEAD.

        marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(
                latitude[i],                        // (DEFINED ABOVE)
                longitude[i]                        // (DEFINED ABOVE)
            ),
            map:map,                                // THE DEFAULT
            shadow:shadow,                          // JUST MY NAME FOR IT (DEFINED ABOVE)
            icon:icon,                              // JUST MY NAME FOR IT (DEFINED ABOVE)
            title:bldgName[i]+" \n"+bldgAddr[i],    // FEEL FREE TO CHANGE THIS BASED ON WHAT YOU NEED
            optimized:false                         // YOU MAY OR MAY NOT NEED THIS
        });
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.NULL); // NULL, DROP, or BOUNCE (all-caps)

        markersArray.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker,i){
            return function(){
                infowindow.setContent('

                    //
                    // INSERT INFOWINDOW CONTENT HERE
                    //

                ');infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
        })(marker,i));

        i++;

    });

}
function updateMap(){

    map.clearOverlays();
    infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var i=1;
    $(".building").each(function(i){

        bldgNo[i] =     $(this).children(".bldg-no").html();        // YOU CAN GET
        bldgName[i] =   $(this).children(".bldg-name").html();      // RID OF ANY
        bldgAddr[i] =   $(this).children(".bldg-address").html();   // OF THESE...
        bldgGfx[i] =    $(this).children(".bldg-graphic").html();   // 
        mainMeter[i] =  $(this).children(".main-meter").html(); // JUST REPLACE
        alarmCount[i] = $(this).children(".alarm-count").html();    // THEM WITH
        latitude[i] =   $(this).children(".latitude").html();       // WHAT YOU'LL 
        longitude[i] =  $(this).children(".longitude").html();      // NEED INSTEAD.

        marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(
                latitude[i],                        // (DEFINED ABOVE)
                longitude[i]                        // (DEFINED ABOVE)
            ),
            map:map,                                // THE DEFAULT
            shadow:shadow,                          // JUST MY NAME FOR IT (DEFINED ABOVE)
            icon:icon,                              // JUST MY NAME FOR IT (DEFINED ABOVE)
            title:bldgName[i]+" \n"+bldgAddr[i],    // FEEL FREE TO CHANGE THIS BASED ON WHAT YOU NEED
            optimized:false                         // YOU MAY OR MAY NOT NEED THIS
        });
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.NULL); // NULL, DROP, or BOUNCE (all-caps)

        markersArray.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker,i){
            return function(){
                infowindow.setContent('

                    //
                    // INSERT UPDATED INFOWINDOW CONTENT HERE
                    //

                ');infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
        })(marker,i));

        i++;

    });

}
```

I'm sure some kinks will need to be worked out of that, but the code I have on my computer (the version not edited for your benefit) works like a charm. If I've mistakenly made any breaks in the code when copying it over and editing it for your ease of use, just let me know and I'll update my answer.

Cheers!

**Edit:** By the way, this code both creates the hidden info windows (the `initMap` function) and updates the hidden info windows (the `updateMap` function). If you call the `updateMap` function at set intervals, it updates the information in your map, which was necessary for my project.

As such, there are code blocks which are very similar/duplicated, because I needed to delete the hidden blocks and create new ones each time the page's InfoWindows updated.

You can simplify it to your needs very easily by deleting the `updateMap` function and any artifacts in `initMap` which were created solely for manipulation in `updateMap`. Then just call the `initMap` function and you're all set!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the common practice when dealing with InfoWindow is to make a global window
and bind it to click event with each marker, instead of making one for each marker.
I made to make a simple app with google markers and this is what I used. Hope this helps!

```
    var globalInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var offset = new google.maps.Size(17,-10);
    globalInfoWindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: offset});

    .
    .
    .        

    for(var i in data.locations)
    {
      var latlng = data.locations[i];

      var lat = Number(latlng[0]);
      var lng = Number(latlng[1]);

      var marker_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: marker_latlng,
        icon: markerImg,
        map: map
      });


    // binds the showing of infowindow with click event.

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', viewLocPic);
    }

    .
    .
    .
    // 'this' in the function refers to the marker itself.
    function viewLocPic()
    {
      console.log("this refers to " + this);
      globalInfoWindow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
      globalInfoWindow.setContent("<img src='cycling.png'/>");
      globalInfoWindow.open(map, this);
    }
```