# Time-based data visualization?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a map online using the Google Maps Javascript API that displays population in certain cities, varying with time. I want the visualization to look somewhat like the "Population" or "Earthquake" demos from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ under the data visualization category.

Basically, I would like it to animate through multiple weeks of data, changing the size of a circle on each city depending on the population in that city at that moment in time.

I have a basic version displaying just one moment in time that I set up with the help of this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circle_add
but I'm not sure how to make it animate with time.

If someone could help point me towards a tutorial that deals with this, or at least point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you find any good examples? I'm looking at the "Time series" below but it's chunky compared to the Google demo.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are others here that will chip in and might give you more details, but I have been thinking about this as well and what comes to mind is a javascript loop to go through the dates here is an example of someone trying to solve an issue around markers, but there seems to be a loop going through an array.

[Add infowindow to looped array of markers on google map using api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507187/add-infowindow-to-looped-array-of-markers-on-google-map-using-api-v3)

Also, here there seems to be a couple of examples though I am about to try them.

[Time series and animated graphics in Google Maps](https://code.google.com/p/playmap/)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @davidsbro please see my answer with edits.

Comment: Thanks, @rakibul_hasan please see my answer with suggested examples to solve the question.